# How to share styles between layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is it possible to share one style between different layers in QGIS? Now if I apply the same style from *.qml or use the same style from Style Manager for different layers then in *.qgs project file each layer contains full copy of the same symbology description. In this case not possible to discriminate layers which use the same style from others. Maybe possible to set name for used style?

I don't want to apply qml to each layer manually (I know about MultuQml plugin) but I want to change style in one place and apply modified style to appropriate layers within project automatically.

But it looks like style descriptions within qgs file doesn't contains any unique identifier which I can use for getting layers with the same styles.